# Using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode method with .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, html-encode

A project using .NET Compact Framework does not allow use System.Web library.

How can I do to HTMLDecode a string using .NET Compact Framework?

I didn't found any class that do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you decompile the .NET Framework source you can get the methods you need. I did it for you, so you can copy and paste the two classes below:

```
internal class HtmlEntities
{
    // Fields
    private static string[] _entitiesList = new string[] { 
            "\"-quot", "&-amp", "<-lt", ">-gt", "\x00a0-nbsp", "\x00a1-iexcl", "\x00a2-cent", "\x00a3-pound", "\x00a4-curren", "\x00a5-yen", "\x00a6-brvbar", "\x00a7-sect", "\x00a8-uml", "\x00a9-copy", "\x00aa-ordf", "\x00ab-laquo", 
            "\x00ac-not", "\x00ad-shy", "\x00ae-reg", "\x00af-macr", "\x00b0-deg", "\x00b1-plusmn", "\x00b2-sup2", "\x00b3-sup3", "\x00b4-acute", "\x00b5-micro", "\x00b6-para", "\x00b7-middot", "\x00b8-cedil", "\x00b9-sup1", "\x00ba-ordm", "\x00bb-raquo", 
            "\x00bc-frac14", "\x00bd-frac12", "\x00be-frac34", "\x00bf-iquest", "\x00c0-Agrave", "\x00c1-Aacute", "\x00c2-Acirc", "\x00c3-Atilde", "\x00c4-Auml", "\x00c5-Aring", "\x00c6-AElig", "\x00c7-Ccedil", "\x00c8-Egrave", "\x00c9-Eacute", "\x00ca-Ecirc", "\x00cb-Euml", 
            "\x00cc-Igrave", "\x00cd-Iacute", "\x00ce-Icirc", "\x00cf-Iuml", "\x00d0-ETH", "\x00d1-Ntilde", "\x00d2-Ograve", "\x00d3-Oacute", "\x00d4-Ocirc", "\x00d5-Otilde", "\x00d6-Ouml", "\x00d7-times", "\x00d8-Oslash", "\x00d9-Ugrave", "\x00da-Uacute", "\x00db-Ucirc", 
            "\x00dc-Uuml", "\x00dd-Yacute", "\x00de-THORN", "\x00df-szlig", "\x00e0-agrave", "\x00e1-aacute", "\x00e2-acirc", "\x00e3-atilde", "\x00e4-auml", "\x00e5-aring", "\x00e6-aelig", "\x00e7-ccedil", "\x00e8-egrave", "\x00e9-eacute", "\x00ea-ecirc", "\x00eb-euml", 
            "\x00ec-igrave", "\x00ed-iacute", "\x00ee-icirc", "\x00ef-iuml", "\x00f0-eth", "\x00f1-ntilde", "\x00f2-ograve", "\x00f3-oacute", "\x00f4-ocirc", "\x00f5-otilde", "\x00f6-ouml", "\x00f7-divide", "\x00f8-oslash", "\x00f9-ugrave", "\x00fa-uacute", "\x00fb-ucirc", 
            "\x00fc-uuml", "\x00fd-yacute", "\x00fe-thorn", "\x00ff-yuml", "Œ-OElig", "œ-oelig", "Š-Scaron", "š-scaron", "Ÿ-Yuml", "ƒ-fnof", "ˆ-circ", "˜-tilde", "Α-Alpha", "Β-Beta", "Γ-Gamma", "Δ-Delta", 
            "Ε-Epsilon", "Ζ-Zeta", "Η-Eta", "Θ-Theta", "Ι-Iota", "Κ-Kappa", "Λ-Lambda", "Μ-Mu", "Ν-Nu", "Ξ-Xi", "Ο-Omicron", "Π-Pi", "Ρ-Rho", "Σ-Sigma", "Τ-Tau", "Υ-Upsilon", 
            "Φ-Phi", "Χ-Chi", "Ψ-Psi", "Ω-Omega", "α-alpha", "β-beta", "γ-gamma", "δ-delta", "ε-epsilon", "ζ-zeta", "η-eta", "θ-theta", "ι-iota", "κ-kappa", "λ-lambda", "μ-mu", 
            "ν-nu", "ξ-xi", "ο-omicron", "π-pi", "ρ-rho", "ς-sigmaf", "σ-sigma", "τ-tau", "υ-upsilon", "φ-phi", "χ-chi", "ψ-psi", "ω-omega", "ϑ-thetasym", "ϒ-upsih", "ϖ-piv", 
            " -ensp", " -emsp", " -thinsp", "‌-zwnj", "‍-zwj", "‎-lrm", "‏-rlm", "–-ndash", "—-mdash", "‘-lsquo", "’-rsquo", "‚-sbquo", "“-ldquo", "”-rdquo", "„-bdquo", "†-dagger", 
            "‡-Dagger", "•-bull", "…-hellip", "‰-permil", "′-prime", "″-Prime", "‹-lsaquo", "›-rsaquo", "‾-oline", "⁄-frasl", "€-euro", "ℑ-image", "℘-weierp", "ℜ-real", "™-trade", "ℵ-alefsym", 
            "←-larr", "↑-uarr", "→-rarr", "↓-darr", "↔-harr", "↵-crarr", "⇐-lArr", "⇑-uArr", "⇒-rArr", "⇓-dArr", "⇔-hArr", "∀-forall", "∂-part", "∃-exist", "∅-empty", "∇-nabla", 
            "∈-isin", "∉-notin", "∋-ni", "∏-prod", "∑-sum", "−-minus", "∗-lowast", "√-radic", "∝-prop", "∞-infin", "∠-ang", "∧-and", "∨-or", "∩-cap", "∪-cup", "∫-int", 
            "∴-there4", "∼-sim", "≅-cong", "≈-asymp", "≠-ne", "≡-equiv", "≤-le", "≥-ge", "⊂-sub", "⊃-sup", "⊄-nsub", "⊆-sube", "⊇-supe", "⊕-oplus", "⊗-otimes", "⊥-perp", 
        };
    private static Hashtable _entitiesLookupTable;
    private static object _lookupLockObject = new object();

    internal static char Lookup(string entity)
    {
        if (_entitiesLookupTable == null)
        {
            lock (_lookupLockObject)
            {
                if (_entitiesLookupTable == null)
                {
                    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
                    foreach (string str in _entitiesList)
                    {
                        hashtable[str.Substring(2)] = str[0];
                    }
                    _entitiesLookupTable = hashtable;
                }
            }
        }
        object obj2 = _entitiesLookupTable[entity];
        if (obj2 != null)
        {
            return (char)obj2;
        }
        return '\0';
    }
}


public sealed class HttpUtility
{
    private static char[] s_entityEndingChars = new char[] { ';', '&' };

    public static string HtmlDecode(string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (s.IndexOf('&') < 0)
        {
            return s;
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter output = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlDecode(s, output);
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static void HtmlDecode(string s, TextWriter output)
    {
        if (s != null)
        {
            if (s.IndexOf('&') < 0)
            {
                output.Write(s);
            }
            else
            {
                int length = s.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    char ch = s[i];
                    if (ch == '&')
                    {
                        int num3 = s.IndexOfAny(s_entityEndingChars, i + 1);
                        if ((num3 > 0) && (s[num3] == ';'))
                        {
                            string entity = s.Substring(i + 1, (num3 - i) - 1);
                            if ((entity.Length > 1) && (entity[0] == '#'))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    if ((entity[1] == 'x') || (entity[1] == 'X'))
                                    {
                                        ch = (char)int.Parse(entity.Substring(2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ch = (char)int.Parse(entity.Substring(1));
                                    }
                                    i = num3;
                                }
                                catch (FormatException)
                                {
                                    i++;
                                }
                                catch (ArgumentException)
                                {
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                i = num3;
                                char ch2 = HtmlEntities.Lookup(entity);
                                if (ch2 != '\0')
                                {
                                    ch = ch2;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    output.Write('&');
                                    output.Write(entity);
                                    output.Write(';');
                                    goto Label_0103;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    output.Write(ch);
                Label_0103: ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jader: I had done that before your suggestion. Another guy suggested to me. But he removed their comment. So, I'll accept your answer as the better way.

Comment: of course you'll want to remove that Hashtable and replace with Dictionary<string, char>. And also get rid of the goto and replace with a continue.

Comment: @Bryan Certainly I'll not want to change Microsoft's code. I will leave it exactly as it was written.

Answer (score 0):

You could always port the code from [Mono](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html), [sample VB code](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19163) or [sample Java code](http://demo.spars.info/j/frameset.cgi?compo_id=207386&packagename=utility&componame=utility.HTMLDecoder&mode=frameset&ref=5&start_class=0) found with a simple web search.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) in the past to find just the methods I need from the framework that aren't included and compile them directly into my compact.net project.